# Error: (Stage "Deploy to Dev" skipped due to when conditional) on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

I am using Jenkins and I would like to deploy my application according to the git branch. Before adding the "when" statements, it runs successfully but as soon as I add the "when" statements, Jenkins runs successfully but returns a clause that makes the deployment not complete and it is shown thus:

```
Stage "Deploy to Dev" skipped due to when conditional
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy to Staging)
[Pipeline] input
Deploy staging deployment?
Proceed or Abort
Approved by admin
Stage "Deploy to Staging" skipped due to when conditional
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy to Production)
[Pipeline] input
Deploy production deployment?
Proceed or Abort
Approved by admin
Stage "Deploy to Production" skipped due to when conditional
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Also, my Jenkins file part for the dev environment is shown thus:

```
  stage('Deploy to Dev') {
      when {branch 'dev'}
      environment {
          KUBECONFIG = credentials('kubeconfig')
      }
      
      steps {
        sh 'kubectl --kubeconfig=${KUBECONFIG} --namespace=${DEV_ENVIRONMENT} --record deployment/api set image deployment/api api=wizelinedevops/samuel:${BUILD_NUMBER}' 
      }
    }

    stage('Deploy to Staging') {
      when {branch 'dev'}
      input{message "Deploy staging deployment?"}
      environment {
          KUBECONFIG = credentials('kubeconfig')
      }
      steps {
        sh 'kubectl --kubeconfig=${KUBECONFIG} --namespace=${STAGING_ENVIRONMENT} --record deployment/api set image deployment/api api=wizelinedevops/samuel:${BUILD_NUMBER}' 
      }
    }

    
    stage('Deploy to Production') {
      when {branch 'master'}
      input{message "Deploy production deployment?"}
      environment {
          KUBECONFIG = credentials('kubeconfig')
      }
      steps {
        sh 'kubectl --kubeconfig=${KUBECONFIG} --namespace=${PROD_ENVIRONMENT} --record deployment/api set image deployment/api api=wizelinedevops/samuel:${BUILD_NUMBER}' 
      }
    }
```

The screenshot is shown below:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QW6u.png)

Comment: Are you using a multibranch pipeline ? Maybe you can try to add a stage to show the branch (using the environment variable GIT_BRANCH or BRANCH_NAME) to see if the branch name is okay.

Comment: Oh wow, yes I just sued the multibranch pipeline - worked like magic!

Comment: okay nice, I post an answer to let you validate the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a multibranch pipeline, see [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when).

> **branch** Execute the stage when the branch being built matches the branch pattern (ANT style path glob) given, for example: when { branch
> 'master' }. Note that this only works on a multibranch Pipeline.